# Projection/Replication in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

My SQL is a bit rusty -- is there a SQL way to project an input table that looks something like this:

```
Name                SlotValue              Slots
----                ---------              -----
ABC                 3                      1
ABC                 4                      2
ABC                 6                      5
```

Into a 'projected' result table that looks like this:

```
Name                SlotSum                 Slot
----                -------                 ----
ABC                 13                      1
ABC                 10                      2
ABC                 6                       3
ABC                 6                       4
ABC                 6                       5
```

In other words, the result set should contain a number of rows equal to MAX(Slots), enumerated (Slot) from 1 to MAX(Slots), and Sum for each of these 'slots' should reflect the sum of the SlotValues projected out to the 'Slots' position. for the pathological case:

```
Name               SlotValue                Slots
----               ---------                -----
ABC                4                        3
```

we should get:

```
Name               SlotSum                  Slot
----               -------                  ----
ABC                4                        1
ABC                4                        2
ABC                4                        3
```

The summation logic is pretty straightforward -- project each SlotValue out to the number of Slots:

```
SlotValue         SlotValue        SlotValue       Slot             Sum
---------         ---------        ---------       ----             ---
3                 4                6               1                13 (3+4+6)
0                 4                6               2                10 (0+4+6)
0                 0                6               3                6 (0+0+6)
0                 0                6               4                6 (0+0+6)
0                 0                6               5                6 (0+0+6)
```

UPDATE: In the end I used a variant of LOCALGHOST's approach in a stored proc. I was hoping there might be a way to do this without a loop.

Comment: ahh i still dont get it, what do you mean by 'project'

Comment: There was a way to do it without loops, but you chose to ignore it. Why?

Comment: Because it would melt the brains of the maintenance grunts that would have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll be able to do this in a view. You'd have to use a procedure.
You could make ProjectedTable a temporary/variable table in the procedure as well. I'd be really interested to see how you'd get this into a view because you need to dynamically generate a range of numbers.

```
declare @maxSlot int 
set @maxSlot = select max(slots) from SlotTable

truncate ProjectedTable
while @i > 0 
    begin
    insert into ProjectedTable (
          SlotSum
          ,Slot
    ) values (
          (select sum(slotValue) from SlotTable where slots >= @maxSlot)
         ,@maxSlot
    )
    set @maxSlot = @maxSlot - 1 
end
select SlotSum, Slot from ProjectedTable
```

Comment: im gettin downvoted, but i dont see why until someone else does it without variables... ;p

Comment: The table variable is there only for demo purposes. It may as well be a normal table, and we just use a WHERE clause.

Comment: ehh, i dunno about that cross join 10s and 1s thing

Comment: I used a variant of this. I think your loop variable needs to be @maxSlot rather than @i though.

Comment: LOCALGHOST: "i dunno?" What kind of critique is that? Just because you never saw a tactic employed before, don't knock it. Yours is procedural. Mine is set-based. This matters to some people, and on some platforms it is the only opportunity.

Comment: i dunno, because the main reason people would argue against using procedural is because it is much slower and doesnt' scale. of course, you couldnt use a view either. however, your method doesn't scale at all

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This will do up to 100 slots in its current form. You can use your imagination to accommodate more.

```
DECLARE @SLOT TABLE
    (
    SlotName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    SlotValue int NOT NULL,
    Slot int NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @SLOT (SlotName, SlotValue, Slot)
    SELECT 'ABC', 3, 1
    UNION
    SELECT 'ABC', 4, 2
    UNION
    SELECT 'ABC', 6, 5

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SLOT.SlotName IS NOT NULL THEN SLOT.SlotName
        ELSE 
            COALESCE(
            (SELECT TOP 1 SL.SlotName FROM @SLOT AS SL WHERE SL.Slot < SLOT_PROJECT.Slot ORDER BY SL.Slot DESC),
            (SELECT TOP 1 SL.SlotName FROM @SLOT AS SL WHERE SL.Slot > SLOT_PROJECT.Slot ORDER BY SL.Slot ASC)
            )
    END AS SlotName,
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(SLOT10.SlotValue)
    FROM
        @SLOT AS SLOT10
    WHERE
        SLOT10.Slot >= SLOT_PROJECT.Slot
    ) AS SlotSum,
    SLOT_PROJECT.Slot
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        (TENS.Seq + ONES.Seq) AS Slot
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 1 AS Seq
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 6
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 8
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 9
        ) AS ONES
        CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT 0 AS Seq
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 20
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 30
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 40
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 50
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 60
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 70
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 80
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 90
        ) AS TENS
    WHERE
        (TENS.Seq + ONES.Seq) <= (SELECT MAX(Slot) FROM @SLOT)
    ) AS SLOT_PROJECT
    LEFT JOIN @SLOT AS SLOT ON
        SLOT.Slot = SLOT_PROJECT.Slot
```